# canvas.toDataURL() creates a png but I want that png to have a certain dimensions

Tags: html, express, canvas, png

basically the png that I create always has dimensions w 300 h 150 and I want larger dimensions. here's what I tried to do.

```
  // this was my last trial I tried canging the width in the canvas tag
var newCanvas = $("<canvas/>", {"class" : "pic", "width" : "1000px", "height" :"300px"}).width(1000).height(500)
//  $(".mainContent").prepend(newCanvas);
// var canvasData = dataGatherer();
var canvas = newCanvas[0];
console.log(canvas)
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial"
console.log("datum---TEST--",  datum)
ctx.fillText(datum.reviewText, 10, 50)
console.log(canvas.toDataURL())
datum.img = canvas.toDataURL();
```

someplace in server:

```
   if(req.body.img){
        var img = req.body.img;
        data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
        var buf = new Buffer(data, "base64");
        fs.unlink(__dirname + "/../public/another.png", function(){
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/../public/another.png", buf, {flag : "w"},function(){
                console.log("++++writen to file+++++")
            })
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must resize the canvas **element** if you want the resulting `.toDataURL` to be resized.

```
var canvas= document.createElement('canvas');

// resize the canvas element -- not it's CSS size
canvas.width=1000;
canvas.height=300;

...

// this dataURL will be 1000 x 300
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: I just found an anwer.. This looks like it works `var newCanvas = $("<canvas class ='pic'></canvas>").attr("height", 400).attr("width", 1000)`

Comment: @jackblank ... Chuckle! That's what I just answered! :-))